# Loading a .rds file in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have downloaded a file with format .rds, How can I load this with Pandas? It is supposed to be an R file but I haven't been able to find any info about how to load it.

Comment: Have you looked into pandas rpy2 R interface?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html

Answer (score 83):

If you would prefer not having to install R (rpy2 requires it), there is a new package "pyreadr" to read  Rds and RData files very easily.

It is a wrapper around the C library librdata, so it is very fast.

You can install it easily with pip:

```
pip install pyreadr
```

Then you can read your rds file:

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('/path/to/file.Rds') # also works for RData

# done! 
# result is a dictionary where keys are the name of objects and the values python
# objects. In the case of Rds there is only one object with None as key
df = result[None] # extract the pandas data frame
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this package.

Comment: Sphafiles are dataframes that have nested objects. Librdata, the C library behind pyreadr currently does not support reading nested objects. In addition it seems those nested objects are lists and librdata currently cannot read lists. For those reasons pyreadr cannot read shape files or other files with similarly complex structure.

Comment: Check that the dlls are in the windows path. See for example this https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat/issues/33. If the problem persist open an issue on github.

Comment: thanks for this package, but when i am using this package its converts my couple of character columns into list, do have some solution for this particular issue, and why is this happening?                                                                                  result = pyreadr.read_r('XYZ.RData')
DF_XYZ = result['MYDATA']

Comment: For reporting bugs please use the issue tracker in the github repo. And please attach a sample file. I need to be able to reproduce the issue otherwise I cannot fix it.

Comment: @OttoFajardo I'm getting an error `LibrdataError: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features` when trying to read a rds file. I've researched the problem and i wasn't able to find the solution. Have you already had this problem before?

Comment: For result[None], I get:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5074acfef18e> in <module>
----> 1 result[None]

KeyError: None  Dataset is: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ISLR_1.2.zip

Comment: If you are referring to Rdata.rds in the data folder, it contains lists, unfortunately pyreadr cannot read list (it is descrived in the README of the github repo. 
Please, in general if you have problems, please submit an issue in the github repo.

Comment: I also am getting the error `pyreadr.custom_errors.LibrdataError: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features`. Actually this seems to not work for any .rds file I've tried.

Comment: Great! Worked successfully!

Answer (score 36):

You could use [the rpy2 interface to Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html), in the following manner:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
df = readRDS('my_file.rds')
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)
# do something with the dataframe
```

Comment: For my file this returns an `robjects.vectors.ListVector`. How can I access the list items?

Comment: This answer in longer valid, the last line produces an error: "AttributeError: module 'rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri' has no attribute 'ri2py'"

Answer (score 19):

To follow up on @mgalardini's answer, in newer versions of rpy2 (version 3.0.4), the method that converts R dataframe to pandas dataframe has changed:

```
>>> rpy2.__version__
'3.0.4'
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
>>> readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
>>> df = readRDS('my_file.rds')
>>> df = pandas2ri.rpy2py_dataframe(df)
```

Comment: Got back error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tzlocal'`

Comment: pip install tzlocal

Comment: I got: AttributeError: 'ListVector' object has no attribute 'rownames' with df = readRDS('d:/src/ISLR/data/Rdata.rds')
df = pandas2ri.rpy2py_dataframe(df)
where the data is from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ISLR_1.2.zip. What can be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me using both `pyreadr` and `rpy2` failed because my rds file was not in a format expected by these two. I kept getting the error `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` with `rpy2` and empty objects while reading with `pyreadr`. My rds file had the data in two lists because of which these options didn't work. Finally, I wrote the following few lines in R to save the results in a CSV:

```
#load data
data = readRDS("inputData.rds")
D = list()
D[[1]] = data[[1]]
D[[2]] = data[[2]]

write.csv(D[[1]],file="first.csv")
write.csv(D[[2]],file="first_1.csv")
```

I hope someone experiencing similar issue will find this helpful.

Comment: pyreadr does not read R lists. Another alternative would have been to save your dataframes independently in a RData file, and then you would be able to read both with pyreadr

Comment: Best answer. pyreadr did not work