# importing rds files in python to be read as a dataframe

Tags: python

I am very new in python. I have written my script in R and did a lot of analyses. But now I found that it should be converted to python. Anyway, I have problem with importing rds files into python, if possible. I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996175/loading-a-rds-file-in-pandas). But, it causes this error

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
df = readRDS('clus_resf.rds')
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)
raise TypeError(msg.format(categories))

TypeError: Parameter 'categories' must be list-like, was <rpy2.rinterface.StrSexpVector - Python:0x2b45d8823e40 / R:0x2b451e7c6d80>
```

you can find my rds file at [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9jeq090z0bcdvi/clus_resf.rds?dl=0)
Many thanks,

Comment: removed the R-tag since this is a python related issue.

Comment: I can reproduce with R 3.4.3, Python 3.6.3 and rpy2. Also with `robjects.r('readRDS("clus_resf.rds")')`.

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure. you mean you got a same error?

Comment: Yes, and I do not get it anymore after updating to rpy2 3.0.0 (it was version 2.9.5 before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug when a certain version of rpy2 and pandas come together. Update them with, e.g.,

```
pip install --upgrade rpy2 pandas
```

and the error should disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had the same issue but could'nt upgrade rpy2. Downgrading pandas from 0.24 to 0.23.4 did the job as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using the package pyreadr looks easier, install

```
pip install pyreadr
```

usage:

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('test_data/basic/one.Rds')

# done! let's see what we got
print(result.keys()) # let's check what objects we got: there is only None
df1 = result[None] # extract the pandas data frame for the only object available
```

With the package you can write .rds files from python too.