# Read in Python an 'sf' spatial dataset exported from R in .rds format

Tags: python, r, geospatial, shapely, r-sf

Is there a way to load into `Python` a spatial dataset exported from `R` in `.rds` format? The class of the original data is an `sf data.frame`. I know it's possible to do this using `rpy2`, `geopandas` and `shapely` but this requires that R is installed locally ([example here](https://github.com/ipeaGIT/geobr/issues/44#issuecomment-509800826)).

The challenge here is to read the file in python without having R installed in the local machine. Is there a way to do this ?

[Here is file that can be used as an example](http://www.ipea.gov.br/geobr/tests/rds/ac.rds).

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996175/loading-a-rds-file-in-pandas

Comment: Hi Bruno. This isn't really a duplicate because in this question the problem is to to solve the problem **without having R installed in the local machine**

Comment: They talk about the pyreadr but that really is limited right now so I don't think it will work here as well

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "No". The RDS file format is R's own object storage format, and there's no implementation outside R to read them.

The long answer is therefore "yes", but it would require someone to read and understand the file format and write an implementation in Python (or C++ interfaced to Python).