# Loading a .RDS file in Python 3

Tags: r, python-3.x, file, save

I have a dataset in RDS format that I managed in RStudio, but I would like to open this in Python to do the analysis. Would it be possible to open this type of format into Python?

I tried the following codes already:

```
pip install pyreadr

import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('/path/to/file.Rds')
```

However, I get a

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 18.9 MiB for an array with shape
> (2483385,) and data type float64.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, you could store the data to a pandas dataframe as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956614/12637995).

The second option([link](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-memory-error/))

> How can I explicitly free memory in Python?

If you wrote a Python program that acts on a large input file to create a few million objects representing and it’s taking tons of memory and you need the best way to tell Python that you no longer need some of the data, and it can be freed?
The Simple answer to this problem is:

> Force the garbage collector for releasing an unreferenced memory with gc.collect().

I hope this answers your query

Answer (score 0):

Pyreadr is a wrapper around the C library librdata, and librdata has a hardcoded limit on the size an R vector can have. The limit used to be very low in old versions, but it was increased. Your vector would fail in older versions but should work in a recent one, so please check that you are using the most recent version.

If that doesn't help, then it may be a bug. If you can share the file please submit an issue in github.

Here a link to the old issues in github librdata and pyreadr (theoretically now solved)

https://github.com/WizardMac/librdata/issues/19.
https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr/issues/3

EDIT:

**The limit is now permently removed in pyreadr 0.3.0. Now this should not be an issue anymore.**