# Conversion to FEATHER file creates huge file

Tags: python, r, feather

I am trying to turn an [`.rds` file](https://gigamove.rwth-aachen.de/en/download/9974ca97aa1dfce793093e2d0828bc5b) into a [`.feather` file](https://www.rstudio.com/blog/feather/) for reading with *Pandas* in *Python*.

```
library(feather)

# Set working directory
data = readRDS("file.rds")
data_year = data[["1986"]]

# Try 1
write_feather(
  data_year,
  "data_year.feather"
  )

# Try 2
write_feather(
  as.data.frame(as.matrix(data_year)),
  "data_year.feather"
)
```

*Try 1* returns `Error: 'x' must be a data frame` and *Try 2* actually writes a `*.feather` file but the file has a size of 4.5GB for a single year whereas the original `*.rds` file has a size of 0.055GB for several years.

How can I turn the file into separate or non-separate `*.feather` files for each year whilst maintaining an adequate file size?

[image]

`data` looks like this:

[image]

`data_year` looks like this:

[image]

*Update

I am open to any suggestions for making the data available for use in NumPy/Pandas whilst maintaining a modest file size!

Comment: `data_year` has length 576M but is a sparse matrix of class `dgCMatrix`. When coerced to data.frame, it will become large, I'm not seeing a way to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment! Would there be any other way to make the data available for use in NumPy/Pandas whilst keeping a modest file size?

Comment: You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996175/loading-a-rds-file-in-pandas).

Comment: @ErfanGhasemi Thank you cor your comment. `pyreadr.read_r('file.rds')` returns `LibrdataError: The file contains an unrecognized object`. The answer of the user mgalardini via your link returns a list vector with each item being an `RS4 object`. I have no idea what that is. Certainly not a pandas data frame. I cannot find an answer via the link you provided.

Comment: Maybe instead of converting from a sparse matrix, you could see if the is a python method to read in the format of sparse matrix that `Matrix::writeMM` writes out EDIT: you could try read in to python using either https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmread.html or https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.hb_read.html depending on what format you write out from R with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `scipy` and `rpy2`, you can read each `dgCMatrix` object directly into Python as a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` object. Both use [compressed sparse column](https://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html) (CSC) format, so there is actually *zero* need for preprocessing. All you need to do is pass the attributes of the `dgCMatrix` object as arguments to the `csc_matrix` constructor.

To test it out, I used R to create an RDS file storing a list of `dgCMatrix` objects:

```r
library("Matrix")
set.seed(1L)

d <- 6L
n <- 10L
l <- replicate(n, sparseMatrix(i = sample(d), j = sample(d), x = sample(d), repr = "C"), simplify = FALSE)
names(l) <- as.character(seq(1986L, length.out = n))

l[["1986"]]
## 6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##                 
## [1,] . . 5 . . .
## [2,] 3 . . . . .
## [3,] . . . . . 6
## [4,] . 2 . . . .
## [5,] . . . . 1 .
## [6,] . . . 4 . .

saveRDS(l, file = "list_of_dgCMatrix.rds")
```

Then, in Python:

```py
from scipy import sparse
from rpy2  import robjects
readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']

l = readRDS('list_of_dgCMatrix.rds')
x = l.rx2('1986') # in R: l[["1986"]]
x
## <rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4 object at 0x120db7b00> [RTYPES.S4SXP]
## R classes: ('dgCMatrix',)

print(x)
## 6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##                 
## [1,] . . 5 . . .
## [2,] 3 . . . . .
## [3,] . . . . . 6
## [4,] . 2 . . . .
## [5,] . . . . 1 .
## [6,] . . . 4 . .

data    = x.do_slot('x')   # in R: x@x
indices = x.do_slot('i')   # in R: x@i
indptr  = x.do_slot('p')   # in R: x@p
shape   = x.do_slot('Dim') # in R: x@Dim or dim(x)

y = sparse.csc_matrix((data, indices, indptr), tuple(shape))
y
## <6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
##         with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

print(y)
##   (1, 0)       3.0
##   (3, 1)       2.0
##   (0, 2)       5.0
##   (5, 3)       4.0
##   (4, 4)       1.0
##   (2, 5)       6.0
```

Here, `y` is an object of class [`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix). You should not need to use the `toarray` method to coerce `y` to an array with dense storage. [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#module-scipy.sparse) implements all of the matrix operations that I can imagine needing. For example, here are the row and column sums of `y`:

```py
y.sum(1) # in R: as.matrix(rowSums(x))
## matrix([[5.],
##         [3.],
##         [6.],
##         [2.],
##         [1.],
##         [4.]])

y.sum(0) # in R: t(as.matrix(colSums(x)))
## matrix([[3., 2., 5., 4., 1., 6.]])
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This is exactly what I need + the last step which you also mentioned `array = sparse.csc_matrix.toarray(y)`. Thanks!

Comment: I was trying express that `toarray` will consume a lot of memory given the size of your matrices. You might be able to do what you need without `toarray`, using the sparse matrix methods available in `scipy.sparse`. Of course, the decision is yours. Glad this helped.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like the following function can be of help.

The function reshapes the sparse matrix to long format eliminating the zeros from it. This will reduce the final data.frame size and disk file size.

```
library(Matrix)
library(feather)

dgcMatrix_to_long_df <- function(x) {
  res <- NULL
  if(nrow(x) > 0L) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
      d <- as.matrix(x[i, , drop = FALSE])
      d <- as.data.frame(d)
      d$row <- i
      d <- tidyr::pivot_longer(d, cols = -row, names_to = "col")
      d <- d[d$value != 0,]
      res <- rbind(res, d)
    }
  }
  res
}

y <- dgcMatrix_to_long_df(data_year)
head(y)
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#    row col      value
#  <int> <chr>    <dbl>
#1     1 Col_0103    51
#2     1 Col_0149     6
#3     1 Col_0188     5
#4     1 Col_0238    89
#5     1 Col_0545    14
#6     1 Col_0547    58


path <- "my_data.feather"
write_feather(y, path)
z <- read_feather(path)
identical(y, z)
#[1] TRUE

# The file size is 232 KB though the initial matrix
# had 1 million elements stored as doubles, 
# for a total of 8 MB, a saving of around 97%
file.size(path)/1024
#[1] 232.0234
```

---

### Edit

The following function is much faster.

```
dgcMatrix_to_long_df2 <- function(x) {
  res <- NULL
  if(nrow(x) > 0L) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
      d <- as.matrix(x[i, , drop = FALSE])
      inx <- which(d != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
      d <- cbind(inx, value = c(d[d != 0]))
      d[, "row"] <- i
      res <- rbind(res, d)
    }
  }
  as.data.frame(res)
}

system.time(y <- dgcMatrix_to_long_df(data_year))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   7.89    0.04    7.92 
system.time(y <- dgcMatrix_to_long_df2(data_year))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.14    0.00    0.14
```

---

### Test data

```
set.seed(2022)
n <- 1e3
x <- rep(0L, n*n)
inx <- sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), n*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.99, 0.01))
x[inx] <- sample(100, sum(inx), replace = TRUE)
data_year <- Matrix(x, n, n, dimnames = list(NULL, sprintf("Col_%04d", 1:n)))
```

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your answer! I ran `test_data = readRDS("file.rds")` and then `test_year = dgcMatrix_to_long_df2(test_data[["1986"]])`. The result is a `data.frame` with the row and col index of non-zero values if I understand correctly. Unfortunately, this makes the import and "recreation" of the structure a bit tricky. I was hoping for a *simple* export/import option but I guess this simply does not exist then. ...

Comment: ps `Matrix` has a summary method (which I think is what you are doing here) e.g. `summary(data_year)`