# reading rds file in python

Tags: python, rdata

When read `rds` file in python following way:

```
import pyreadr
df = prreadr.read_r('/home/test.rds')
```

to turn `df` into `DataFrame`, I tried:

`pd.DataFrame(df)` - I get `If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` message

`pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['a','b','c'])` - I get columns with `NaN`

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient = 'index', columns = ['a','b','c'])` - I get `Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (1, 11)` message

I want to read `rds` file in Python and turn it into `DataFrame`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading a .rds file in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996175/loading-a-rds-file-in-pandas)

Comment: As you can see from the link above, the `pyreadr` module currently does not support nested objects.

Comment: You are already reading the rds file in python as pandas dataframe with `pyreadr.read_r('/home/test.rds')` - I'm assuming that `prreadr.read_r` had a typo introduced when you typed your question.  [Here's](https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadr/_build/html/index.html#pyreadr.pyreadr.read_r) the documentation on `pyreadr.read`

Comment: `import pyreadr`
`df = pyreadr.read_r('/home/test.rds')` `df` type is OrderdDict. May be I need find a way to manipulate OrderedDict Fomat? instead of tun it into DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

when using read_r, it returns a dictionary. You should first look at what keys you got in your dictionary, each of those elements is a dataframe. In the case of rdata files y can multiple dataframes per file, that is why you can get multiple elements in your dictionary. In the case of rds files you can get only one element and therefore you have only one element with the key None. So do this (observe the None in square brackets)

```
import pyreadr
df = prreadr.read_r('/home/test.rds')[None]
```